# How come pointers assigned to a string don't manipulate the original string as a whole?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Sample code is:

```
void main()
{
    char stringy[] = "I am so dumb what is wrong with me";
    char *pStringy = stringy;

    pStringy = "please be gentle";

    printf("%s", stringy);
}
```

Output is:

```
I am so dumb what is wrong with me
```

(This is probably really basic, but I don't understand, and couldn't find the question (probably because I just didn't know how to phrase it))

I'm wondering why the output isn't "please be gentle" when -after pStringy is initialized- pStringy and stringy share the same memory address.

In contrast, doing the exact same thing with single values (but not arrays) works just like I'd expect, and the original value in the original variable gets changed.

Comment: Compare to what happens if you do `*pStringy = 'X';`

Comment: @aschepler: undefined behaviour if you do this after the second assignment.

Comment: Yes, I meant to try `*pStringy = 'X';` instead of `pStringy = "please be gentle";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers *point* at other parts of memory. They don't contain or own the things they point at.

Here is a badly drawn MS paint sketch of your computer's memory Before and After the line:

```
pString = "please be gentle"
```

[image: Pointer diagram]

Hopefully this clears things up for you. As you can see, `stringy` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Because you print **stringy** instead of pStringy.
Anyway try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)    {
    char stringy[] = "I am so dumb what is wrong with me";
    char *pStringy = stringy;

    pStringy = "please be gentle";
    printf("%s\n%s",stringy, pStringy);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> I am so dumb what is wrong with me
> please be gentle
> ```

You should know that main should be at least **int main(void){}**

EDIT:

There some things which you have to undestand.

1) pString point to stringy.

2) latter pString point to another memory location (read only).

3) So at this point pStringy doesn't point to **stringy** any more, which means, that, there is no modified Array as you expected.

Comment: Well, you never tried to change that array, you only assign that pointer to it. That's all.

Comment: .@rakeb.void Did you even saw how many times the OP changed he's Question ?

Comment: Now your answer is ok.

Comment: @JawiMmm Starting with c99 there is no need of return 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
char stringy[] = "I am so dumb what is wrong with me";
char *pStringy = stringy; //pStringy  point to stringy array

pStringy = "please be gentle";// instead of writing to stringy
                              // trough the pointer pStringy 
                              // you assigned pStringy a new address
                              // of the string "please be gentle"

printf("%s\n",stringy);       //printf will still print the old value
                              // "I am so dumb what is wrong with me"

                              // the proper way was to copy that string
                              // to the pointer using strcpy
                              // as so:
pStringy = stringy;
strcpy(pStringy , "please be gentle");

// now printf will print "please be gentle"
// instead of the old value
// "I am so dumb what is wrong with me"

printf("%s\n",stringy);
;
```

Comment: string literals are immutable. Without the assignment, it would be ok, because `stringy` was a `char` array (and not a string literal). But like shown in your answer, you try overwriting a string literal which will most probably just crash.

Comment: @FelixPalmen why you think it will crash?. `char p[]="some text"` you can overwrite this one, but not this `char *p="some text"` .

Comment: Ok, sorry to say that but your answers are just *sloppy* ... then make that explicit, please. Your code looks like trying to `strcpy()` to a pointer pointing to a string literal.

Comment: @FelixPalmen please reread my answer carefully. where is the mistake in it. please do it carefully as i said.

Comment: @FelixPalmen i am going to modify my post to make it clearer (i hope)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92780/discussion-between-milevyo-and-felix-palmen).

Answer (score 0):

this is what your compiler did.

<del>`char *pStringy = stringy;`</del>

`pStringy = "please be gentle";`

assigning a pointer to a value, then assigning **same poiter** to another value, is always yielding to the last value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You set `pStringy` to point to the first message with

```
char *pStringy = stringy;
```

Then you overwrite that pointer with another message

```
pStringy = "please be gentle";
```

but you completely ignore that, and print the original message with

```
printf("%s", stringy);
```

so it prints

```
I am so dumb what is wrong with me
```

Answer (score 0):

In C arrays and pointers are very similar (this is not completely true since there are some very small and obscure differences). When you write

```
char stringy[] = "I am so dumb what is wrong with me";
```

you could get the same result by writing

```
char * stringy = "I am so dumb what is wrong with me";
```

When you make the assignment

```
char *pStringy = stringy;
```

both pointers point to the same data. If it weren't string literals you would be able to modify them like this.

```
pStringy[3] = 'f';
```

But you can't since they are in fact string literals.

Edit: you can do that, my C knowledge is getting worse

The real problem is that you assign the pointer to something else so now it will point to a completely different value. You can test this with the following code:

```
void main()
{
char stringy[] = "I am so dumb what is wrong with me";
char *pStringy = stringy;

//print the addresses before assigning pStringy
printf("%d\n%d\n", stringy, pStringy);

pStringy = "please be gentle";

printf("%s\n%s\n", stringy, pStringy);

//print the addresses after assigning pStringy
printf("%d\n%d\n", stringy, pStringy);

}
```

Comment: Using the `char stringy[]` version, it is in fact legal to do `pStringy[3] = 'f';`